# Alarm manager not going off when specific calendar set time

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a new intent at a specific time (around now, Sunday 12:36AM as of this post) after the user clicks a button. I've looked at all the calendar class tutorials but can't seem to find whats wrong. I've tested the code without the calendar functions and it works fine. Code below:

```
public void myClickHandler(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.button_start:
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alrmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alrmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the day of the week incorrectly. `Calendar.SUNDAY = 1`, so change as follows:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
```

Or, better yet, use the class constants:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

Comment: WOW THANK YOU! The examples I looked at were wrong in setting the day number.

Comment: Yeah, the `Calendar` class values are weird. E.g., days of the week are 1-based, but months are 0-based. It's always better just to use the class constants, if possible.

Comment: By the way, when you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, it returns an instance with the current time already set. Just FYI.